# Remove Local Bookmarks in QTerminal

Tags: lubuntu, 21.10, lxqt

Is possible to remove Local Bookmarks in side panel in `qterminal` ?
When entering to the preferences in qterminal (File->Preferences->Bookmarks) there is only possibility to add bookmarks.

Regards.

Comment: local bookmarks?   Do you mean the *bookmarks* that appear in `pcmanfm-qt` (when used as a file-manager; ie. https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/2/2.4/2.4.4/pcmanfm-qt.html?highlight=bookmarks) or something else?

Comment: No, `qterminal` has own bookmarks named `Local Bookmarks`

Comment: Sorry I though you wanted to use a terminal command (ie. CLI answer) for altering a LXQt setting...     Try looking in `/home/$USER/.config/qterminal.org/qterminal_bookmarks.xml`   (I have no bookmarks on this box so have no such file;  I'm also not on *impish* so the file may differ slightly for you; the location will be where `qterminal` settings report it is anyway)

Comment: Looks that these bookmarks are hardcoded in `https://github.com/lxqt/qterminal/blob/master/src/bookmarkswidget.cpp`